# Why can Sailor Pluto be away from the Space-Time Door?

Tags: sailor-moon

In the classic 90s anime, Sailor Pluto was commissioned by Queen Serenity (mom of Princess Serenity [Sailor Moon's ancient incarnation]) to guard the Space-Time Door, which she is shown doing in the *R* season, but she is later allowed to leave, and thus shows up with a civilian form (Setsuna) in the *S* season.  One of the 3 rules given by Queen Serenity was that she could not leave her post at the door.  She does go on to break all of the rules, but [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailor_Pluto#Profile), Neo-Queen Serenity (future Sailor Moon) **gives her permission to leave her post**.

**But why?  Does the door not need to be guarded anymore?**  Is it **temporary leave** and she will need to return eventually, or is it **permanent leave**?

In the manga, Sailor Pluto's guarding location might be located **outside of time** (or is it located inside of the palace in 30th century Crystal Tokyo?), so perhaps she could technically be there as well as have a 20th century civilian incarnation that is at a point **inside of time**, so she could apparently continue to guard the door *while* she shows up in *S*, the *SuperS* movie, and *Sailor Stars* (but this is unrelated to why Neo Queen Serenity would excuse her from her post in the classic anime).

In the ***Sailor Moon Crystal* canon**, is Sailor Pluto able to and/or permitted to leave her post at the door? Is this aspect **identical to the manga version**?

Comment: I'm stuck now with something similar. In the Dark Moon arc of SMC, it seems to be implied that Sailor Pluto can't leave because someone needs to watch the door; Diana tells Pluto she will replace her and that Pluto should help the Guardians. Diana is back in present day Japan with Chibi-usa in the Death Busters arc, which is when Pluto appears in the present day. But it's possible I might have missed some details here and there, or that some details (similar to those in the answers) have yet to be revealed.

Comment: @Maroon I corresponded w/ [Kimiski](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/641799), who has written fanfic involving minute details of the _R_ season. She wrote of the 90s anime, "they never really explain that. Setsuna just tells the girls she came from the future to tell them of the Messiah and pending destruction, but has to work with Neptune and Uranus. . . . I don't think they mention the three rules about guarding the door in the anime (until _S_ when Pluto stops time to let Neptune and Uranus enter the building), I think they just say she has to stay because its her duty- well- I guess her . . .

Comment: . . . duty changed in season _S_. . . loop-holes in the anime . . . There are a lot. . . . I'm pretty sure Pluto never says anymore than it is a taboo, I always assumed she just meant . . . a taboo against the universe and creation, and we're left to assume how she learned about it or who told her (in the manga we can say Queen Serenity, but then who told Queen Serenity? Did someone tell her? Was she just born with that knowledge?).” It sounds like _SMC_ is the same as the 90s anime in that Setsuna & Diana are both in present-day Tokyo at the same time w/o explanation of how the door is safe.

Answer (score 1):

In the Crystal continuity it is unknown as it is a work in progress, and did not progress too much further from Pluto's introduction, so it is **unknown for Crystal continuity** if she will leave the door or not. There is still no canon material on the matter.

As to why she can leave the door, she has the power to seal off entire worlds out of the fourth dimension (the time dimension)[(ref)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSailor_Pluto%20&cd=7&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br&lr=lang_en%7Clang_pt#Special_powers_and_items).

Since you need a time-space key to safely navigate fouth dimension, she could secure all keys, lock the access to the place where the keys were stored and leave for a short time.

Probably her leave cannot be defined as permanent or temporary. Since the fourth dimension is outside normal time, she can safely exists in the fourth dimension and outside it:

> However, for all intents and purposes, in the manga the technicality of Sailor Pluto existing outside of time means she is able to be reincarnated as a normal woman while still existing back at her post at the Time Gate.[(ref)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSailor_Pluto%20&cd=7&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br&lr=lang_en%7Clang_pt#Profile)

Sailor Pluto's racial status is also subject of controversy. While Endymion/Tuxedo Mask is from the Earth realm, Usagi/Sailor Moon is from the Silver Millenium race, the other sailor senshi seem to be reincarnated humans, Sailor Pluto is more of a goddess than a human:

> She is also stated to be the daughter of Chronos, god of time. (manga act 18, original anime ep. 82).

They made significant changes in Crystal from the original Sailor Moon works (like giving Tuxedo Mask an attack), so I wouldn't expect it to be identical, but to follow closely.

You can compare Crystal and the original making a parallel between the original Yamato series and Yamato 2099 that aired in 2014. They tend to follow the original work closely, but making adaptations and concessions to suit XXI century's scientific and social developments.

Comment: should also point out that (at least on Wikipedia) it also mentions Sailor Venus is thought to be a goddess as well (the Goddess of Love)

Comment: @Mindwin, Thanks for this helpful answer; I’d be happy to select it as correct if you can add in 1) why is Pluto given permission to leave the door in the 90s anime? I read online that Neo Queen Serenity gave permission; is this true or a fan theory? I tried watching R & S episodes that Pluto is in but I couldn’t find it. And 2) Wikipedia says her post is located outside of time in the manga, but in which chapter is that shown/stated? It looked like Chibi-usa walked right up to Pluto while exploring a remote area of the palace, not that she had to exit her own dimension to meet Pluto. . . .

Comment: . . . I also tried looking for this in the manga but didn’t find the source. Would be a great aid if you can help! Also curious: if Pluto can hide the keys and the fourth dimension can’t be entered (i.e. everything is safe while she’s away), why would she have ever needed to guard the door in the first place and have to be lonely for hundreds of years? Is this a plot hole?

Comment: She does leave in episode 24 of SMC, after Diana tells her that this is the time to do so (because the other Sailor Guardians are fighting against Black Moon and Chibi-usa is in trouble), and says that she will substitute for her as a guardian. Not sure if she will return anytime soon to the gate though. It sounds like one of the reasons she can't leave is that a gatekeeper is needed, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Uhm Tuxedo Mask getting an attack (smoking bomber) is also canon in the manga or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

In the manga, as she the daughter of the god of time, she has a strong connection to the Space-Time Door and can control it from anywhere. She even used an attack with the Garnet Rod, *Dark Dome Close* to close the Door from the 20th century. However, she sometimes cannot use this abilities, such as in case of an eclipse - that's why the Dead Moon Circus arrived in time of an eclipse. In Crystal, as it's following the manga, it might be the same.

In the anime, this wasn't explained too much, as Setsuna was a minor character.

Answer (score 0):

You're not thinking fourth-dimensionally. (As Doctor Emmet Brown says).

The Space-Time Door exists outside of the Physical Realm. And as the name says, this door lets the people travel through Time and Space.

I'm sure that as Sailor Moon and Tuxedo Mask can find themselves at the future, Pluto can Stand at the door and in XX century Tokyo at the same time.

Remember that she left the others at the end of the Death Busters Arch, to help rise Hotaru Tomoe after she uses her Death Reborn Revolution Attack and return as a baby.

The episode when she appears in front of Chibi Moon at the middle of Sailor Moon S is the episode when Pluto mentions the permission that Neo Queen Serenity gave her to travel at that time.